# Find difference between 2 recent transactions in 2 different weeks grouped by ID in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as shown below

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1,1), Start_Date = c("01-09-17", 
"01-09-17", "08-09-17", "08-09-17", "08-09-17","15-09-17","15-09-17"), End_Date = c("07-09-17", 
"07-09-17", "14-09-17", "14-09-17", "14-09-17","21-09-17","21-09-17"), Policy1_Date = c("05-09-17", 
NA, "09-09-17", NA, "10-09-17","16-09-17","17-09-17"), Policy2_Date = c(NA, "06-09-17", 
"08-09-17", "09-09-17", "10-09-17",NA,NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

What I need ? - For each ID, I am  supposed to calculate the difference between 2 dates (for each policy). Start_Date and End_Date depicts the start and end of week. Policy1_Date and Policy2_Date shows transaction dates and the weeks they fall into. For each week date, I want to find out the difference between dates in the way described below:

**Policy1**
For each week, say 08-09-17 till 14-09-17, I will take the Start date of week (08-09-17) and take the difference with the just previous date (not falling in the same week) i.e. 05-09-17. **It should take previous non-NA date**

**Policy2**
For each week, say 08-09-17 till 14-09-17, I need difference between 08-09-17 and 06-09-17.

In case there is no previous date available, I will simply put NA. For example, for week 01-09-17 till 07-09-17, latest transaction was 05-09-17 but there is no previous transaction available. I will mark NA for this week.

**Final Output**
This will have 5 columns (ID, Start_Date, End_Date, Policy1_gap, Policy2_gap).

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1), Start_Date = c("01-09-17", "08-09-17", 
"15-09-17"), End_Date = c("07-09-17", "14-09-17", "21-09-17"), 
    Policy1_Gap = c(NA, 5, 7), Policy2_Gap = c(NA, 4, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Note: Entire aggregation will happen for each group/ID. I will not take difference between dates for 2 different groups/ID

Comment: Hi - I have added 1 more week in my input dataset and also added desired output. Can we look for data.table solution as my dataset is very large ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`:

```
cols <- c("Policy1_Date", "Policy2_Date")
#convert columns into Date class
DT[, c("Start_Date", "End_Date", cols) := lapply(.SD, as.IDate, format="%d-%m-%y"), 
    .SDcols=c("Start_Date", "End_Date", cols)]

#for each ID, Start_Date and End_Date, find the last non-NA date for each column
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) last(x[!is.na(x)])), .(ID, Start_Date, End_Date), .SDcols=cols][,
    #calculate the gap between dates
    c("Policy1_Gap","Policy2_Gap") := lapply(.SD, function(x) c(NA_integer_, diff(x))), ID, .SDcols=cols][,
        c("Policy1_Diff","Policy2_Diff") := lapply(.SD, function(x) Start_Date - shift(x)), ID, .SDcols=cols][]
```

output:

```
   ID Start_Date   End_Date Policy1_Date Policy2_Date Policy1_Gap Policy2_Gap Policy1_Diff Policy2_Diff
1:  1 2017-09-01 2017-09-07   2017-09-05   2017-09-06          NA          NA           NA           NA
2:  1 2017-09-08 2017-09-14   2017-09-10   2017-09-10           5           4            3            2
3:  1 2017-09-15 2017-09-21   2017-09-17         <NA>           7          NA            5            5
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- setDT(structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1,1), Start_Date = c("01-09-17", 
    "01-09-17", "08-09-17", "08-09-17", "08-09-17","15-09-17","15-09-17"), End_Date = c("07-09-17", 
        "07-09-17", "14-09-17", "14-09-17", "14-09-17","21-09-17","21-09-17"), Policy1_Date = c("05-09-17", 
            NA, "09-09-17", NA, "10-09-17","16-09-17","17-09-17"), Policy2_Date = c(NA, "06-09-17", 
                "08-09-17", "09-09-17", "10-09-17",NA,NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                    -5L)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I have a little modification in the explanation. In case, I need difference of Start_Date (08-09-17) and just previous date (05-09-17), what change should I make in your solution ?

Comment: do you mean add one more column?

Comment: i added something for your additional requirement

Comment: Yes, where I will get difference in dates in another way i.e. Start_Date (of current week) - just previous date (not from same week). diff(08-09-17, 05-09-17)=3

Comment: Referring to your solution, Shift(x) will shift the values by 1 place. If there is 'NA' between 2 policy dates then it would give NA as the difference. For ex: we have 3 weeks (W1, W2, W3) and there are no transactions for W2 (i.e. NA) then according to your solution it will be Start_Date (W3) - last txn (W2). It should take last non-NA txn as per requirement i.e. Start_Date (W3) - last txn (W1)

Comment: I think you forgot to update your desired output after updating the question